# SQL for sorting boolean column as true, null, false

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, boolean

My table has three boolean fields: f1, f2, f3. If I do

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY f1, f2, f3
```

the records will be sorted by these fields in the order false, true, null. I wish to order them with null in between true and false: the correct order should be true, null, false.

I am using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Not beautiful, but should work:

```
   ... order by (case when f1 then 1 when f1 is null then 2 else 3 end) asc
```

Comment: Obviously you would have to do the same for each of the other variables.

Comment: +1.  Let's make it uglier:  `ORDER BY COALESCE((NOT bool_field)::INTEGER * 2, 1)`. :)

Comment: ERROR: Function isnull(boolean) does not exist

Comment: @pilcrow thanks) really need to cast to int since ```COALESCE(bool_field, true)``` does not order properly

Answer (score 47):

A better solution would be to use

`f1 DESC NULLS LAST`

if you're okay with the order true, false, nil ( I guess the important part of your question was, like in my situation now, to have the not-true vaules together)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7621232/1627888

Comment: While this is useful, it doesn't answer the question, since there are cases where you really want `null` in between `true` and `false`.

Comment: It might be worth considering an enum if `NULL` is not fine either at the beginning or at the end. In general a nullable boolean should become an enum

Comment: I love this. Can't vote it up because it doesn't fit the question, but I didn't know about `NULLS LAST`, will be using it for sure.

Answer (score 10):

This should work better

```
order by (f1 is true) desc
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Great answer! I needed to sort a query according to a boolean column and it worked perfectly.

Comment: In my test this answer placed the values in order `true, false, null`

Answer (score 7):

you could do also as follows:

```
order by coalesce(f1, FALSE), coalesce(f1, TRUE), ...
```

If `f1` is `TRUE`,  you get: `TRUE, TRUE`
If `f1` is `NULL`,  you get: `FALSE, TRUE`
If `f1` is `FALSE`, you get: `FALSE, FALSE`

which corresponds to the sorting order you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort any finite set of things in any order by using a case statement to map the elements to the counting numbers ...

Answer (score -1):

It is also possible to do as follows:

```
... ORDER BY (CASE WHEN f1 IS NOT NULL THEN f1::int * 2 ELSE 1 END) DESC
```