# Sort NULL values to the end of a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, sql-order-by

Is there a way with PostgreSQL to sort rows with `NULL` values in fields to the end of the selected table?

Like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY somevalue, PUT_NULL_TO_END
```

Answer (score 273, accepted):

`NULL` values *are* sorted last in default *ascending* order. You don't have to do anything extra.

The issue applies to ***descending*** order, which is the perfect inverse and thus sorts `NULL` values on top.
**PostgreSQL 8.3** introduced `NULLS LAST`:

```
ORDER BY somevalue DESC NULLS LAST
```

For **PostgreSQL 8.2** and older or other **RDBMS without this standard SQL** feature:

```
ORDER BY (somevalue IS NULL), somevalue DESC
```

`FALSE` sorts before `TRUE`, so `NULL` values come last, just like in the example above.

See:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)
- [The manual on `SELECT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html)

Comment: IMHO in most real world applications you would want null values last whatever the order. For example sorting DESC on an optional timestamp, firstname, lastname, ... so I find it really suspect even though it seems to make sense that mathematically DESC order is the opposite of ASC. Maybe the nulls are just to be in a category of their own and should not be affected by ASC, DESC and always put last, that would have been a better default.

Comment: It could affect the indexes if they are DESC maybe you could add a note about that too ? https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/AANLkTinvi12K%3DcK50nLiFSsCGUq3Ven0tLRW_6w2H-3E%40mail.gmail.com

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy: Indexes matching the sort order are touched in the linked answer above.

Comment: Personally I think the default should have been the opposite: NULLs come first in ascending order, and last in descending order. That's much more intuitive, as NULL is the "smallest" value.

Comment: For people coming from MYSQL , this is a lol? Why was it built like this in the first place. OR did Mysql over optimize the result

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy: IMHO in the real world there are more much more uses cases where NULL should be the "smallest" value. So, this default implementation is kind of weird like a lot of other things in postgres.

Answer (score 68):

Does this make the trick?

```
ORDER BY somevalue DESC NULLS LAST
```

Taken from: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html

Comment: The accepted solution works but I prefer this better for a few reasons: 1) It's non-intuitive (to me at least) that `DESC` prioritizes `null` in the first place, 2) This command is actually obvious to what it's going to do with the result