# Select latest row before for given date

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, greatest-n-per-group

I try to compare a date with dates which are in different rows. I hope the picture makes it clear.

For example:

The Product with ID "2" in "June" should have a fee of 100$ because the fee was valid from April to July.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that plain *text* is very much preferred for data. Not images. Always declare your version of Postgres. And try to make your task clear. There is room for interpretation in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single given `product_id`:

```
SELECT * -- which columns do you need?
FROM   product    p
JOIN   productfee f ON f.valid_from <= p.date
WHERE  p.product_id = 2
ORDER  BY f.valid_from DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

If tables are of non-trivial size, you'd better have at least these indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX ON product (product_id);
CREATE INDEX ON productfee (valid_from DESC);
```

(Or more specialize, depending on the complete picture.)

If `valid_from` can be `NULL`, consider `NULLS LAST`. See:

- [Sort NULL values to the end of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621205/sort-null-values-to-the-end-of-a-table/7622046#7622046)

Obviously, you'll use proper `date` or `timestamp` types, not just month names.