# Update based on same column

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sql-update

I have a table like this:

```
ID | Flag
-----------
 1 | True
 1 | True
 1 | NULL
 1 | True
 1 | NULL
 2 | False
 2 | False
 2 | False
 2 | NULL
 2 | NULL
```

And I want an output like this:

```
ID | Flag
-----------
 1 | True
 1 | True
 1 | True
 1 | True
 1 | True
 2 | False
 2 | False
 2 | False
 2 | False
 2 | False
```

I want to replace nulls with the value assigned in different records. Is there a way to do it in a single update statement?

Comment: Why do you have ID but it's not a Primary Key ? You should change the name to [SOMETHING_ID], instead of 'ID' only. Then add new column 'ID' as a primary key, it will make your life easier.

Answer (score 2):

One option uses a correlated subquery:

```
update mytable t
set flag = (select bool_or(flag) from mytable t1 where t1.id = t.id)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a1b4b52ec64b624e6a4fb1bbc73046e3)**:

```
id | flag
-: | :---
 1 | t   
 1 | t   
 1 | t   
 1 | t   
 1 | t   
 2 | f   
 2 | f   
 2 | f   
 2 | f   
 2 | f
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `exists`:

```
update t
     set flag = exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.flag);
```

The advantage of `exists` over a subquery with aggregation is performance:  the query can stop at the first row where `flag` is true.  This is a simple index lookup on an index on `(id, flag)`.

Performance would be more improved by limiting the number of rows being updated.  That actually suggests two separate statements:

```
update t
    set flag = true
    where (flag is null or not flag) and
          exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.flag);

update t
    set flag = false
    where (flag is null or flag) and
          not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and not t2.flag);
```

These could be combined into a single (more complicated) statement, but the sets being updated are disjoint.  This limits the updates to the rows that need to be updated, as well as limiting the subquery to a simple lookup (assuming an index on `(id, flag)`).

Answer (score 0):

The answers provided satisfy your sample data, but may still leave you short of a satisfactory answer. That is because your sample data is missing a couple significant sets. What happens if you had the following, either instead of or in addition to your current sample data?

```
+----+-------+
| id | flag  |
+----+-------+
|  3 | true  |
|  3 | false |
|  3 | null  |
|  4 | null  |
|  4 | null  |
+----+-------+
```

The answer could be significantly different.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (like your sample data suggests):

- There can never be the same `id` with `true` *and* `false` in the set. Else, you'd have to define what to do.
- `null` values remain unchanged if there is no non-null value for the same `id`.

This should give you best performance:

```
UPDATE tbl t
SET    flag = t1.flag
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)
          id, flag
   FROM   tbl
   ORDER  BY id, flag
   ) t1                      -- avoid repeated computation for same id
WHERE  t.id = t1.id
AND    t.flag IS NULL        -- avoid costly no-op updates
AND    t1.flag IS NOT NULL;  -- avoid costly no-op updates;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e662715ebfb780c3e696d8984b8b7715)*

The subquery `t1` distills target values per id *once*.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)
       id, flag
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY id, flag;
```

Since `null` sorts last, it effectively grabs the first non-null value per `id`. `false` sorts before `true`, but that has no bearing on the case as there can never be both for the same `id`. See:

- [Sort NULL values to the end of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621205/sort-null-values-to-the-end-of-a-table/7622046#7622046)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

If you have *many* rows per `id`, there are faster techniques:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)

The added conditions in the outer query prevent all no-op updates from happening, thus avoiding major cost. Only rows are updated where a `null` value actually changes. See:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)