# Unify columns from different tables while selecting distinct rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

### Tables

User

| id | name | email | is_active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | john@albert.com | FALSE |
| 2 | mike | mike@ss.com | TRUE |
| 3 | monica | monica@dunno.com | TRUE |
| 4 | joey | joey@as.com | FALSE |
| 5 | ross | ross@boss.com | FALSE |

Subscriptions

| id | house_id | plan name | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A banana a month | inactive |
| 2 | 2 | An apple a month | active |
| 3 | 3 | A pear a month | active |

House

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John's House |
| 2 | Mike's House |
| 3 | Monica's House |
| 4 | Joey's House |
| 5 | Ross's House |

House_Contact (legacy table)

| id | house_id | is_primary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | TRUE |
| 2 | 2 | FALSE |
| 2 | 3 | TRUE |

House_User (new table)

| id | house_id | is_owner | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | FALSE | 2 |
| 2 | 4 | FALSE | 4 |
| 3 | 5 | FALSE | 5 |

### Expected Results

The resulting table should include the following:

- Does the user have a subscription regardless of status? If so, include, if not, disregard.
- Get `email` & `is_active` from User table (if they have subscription)
- Get `is_primary` OR `is_owner` (if they have a subscription)
- Results should be distinct (no duplicate users)

| house_id | email | is_owner | is_active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john@albert.com | TRUE | FALSE |
| 2 | mike@ss.com | FALSE | TRUE |
| 3 | monica@dunno.com | TRUE | TRUE |

## What I tried

```
SELECT
    u.email AS "email",
    u.is_active AS "is_active",
    h.id AS "house_id",
    is_owner
FROM
    house c
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            house_id,
            user_id
        FROM
            house_user) hu ON h.id = hu.house_id
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            id,
            email,
            is_active
        FROM
            USER) u ON hu.user_id = u.id
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            id,
            email,
            is_primary
        FROM
            house_contact) hc ON u.email = ch.email
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            house_id,
            is_primary is_owner
        FROM
            house_contact
    UNION
    SELECT
        house_id,
        is_owner is_owner
    FROM
        house_user) t ON u.id = t.house_id)
ORDER BY
    u.email
```

Results are half than if I remove the `INNER JOIN` with `UNION` statement. No idea how to proceed.

I'm particularly confused with unifying the column and the possible duplication.

Comment: Can you explain the results *in English*?  The logic is not obvious.  It is also really unclear how the tables are related to each other.  They all have ids but what ids correspond to what?

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) for this problem?

Comment: Why are you doing `....INNER JOIN (SELECT ..... table ) ON....` and not the much simpler   `..INNER JOIN table ON ....` ???

Comment: How does `is_owner` become "true" when there are no true values in the data?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've edited the expected results to clarify. But `is_owner` should either get from `is_primary` or `is_owner` from either `house_contact` or `house_user`, whichever has the record. They may be duplicated or they may not exist in one.

Comment: This cannot be the code you tried. "user" is a reserved word. `FROM USER` would raise an error. Did you simplify table names? And unmatched `)` at the end. Also: If there are both `is_primary` and `is_owner`, then which takes precedence? And we need to know actual table definitions showing all constraints (in particular PK, FK and NOT NULL) to be sure. And *always* your version of Postgres, just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My educated guess:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (u.id)
      u.id, u.email, u.is_active, h.house_id, h.is_primary
FROM  "user" u
LEFT  JOIN (
   SELECT hu.user_id, hu.house_id
        , GREATEST(hc.is_primary, hu.is_owner) AS is_primary
   FROM   house_user hu
   LEFT   JOIN house_contact hc USING (house_id)
   WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT FROM subscription WHERE house_id = hu.house_id)
   ) h ON h.user_id = u.id
ORDER  BY u.id, h.is_primary DESC NULLS LAST, h.house_id;
```

We don't need table `house` in the query at all.

I see **three** possible sources of conflict:

1. `house_contact.is_primary` vs. `house_user.is_owner`. Both seem to mean the same. The DB design is broken in this respect. Taking `GREATEST()` of both, which means `true` if either is `true`.
2. We don't care about `subscription.status`, so just make sure the house has at least one subscription of any kind with `EXISTS`, thereby avoiding possible duplicates a priori.
3. A user can live in multiple houses. We want only *one* row per user. So show the first house with `is_primary` (the one with the smallest `house_id`) if any. If there is no house, there is also no subscription. But the outer `LEFT JOIN` keeps the user in the result. Change to `JOIN` to skip users without subscription.

About `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

About sorting boolean values:

- [Sorting null values after all others, except special](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891803/sorting-null-values-after-all-others-except-special/21892611#21892611)
- [Sort NULL values to the end of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621205/sort-null-values-to-the-end-of-a-table/7622046#7622046)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `joins` as follows:

```
Select distinct hu.house_id, u.email, hu.is_owner, hc.is_primary
  From user u join house_user hu on u.id = hu.user_id
  Join subscriptions s on s.house_id = hu.house_id
  Join house_contract hc on hc.house_id = s.house_id;
```

I have used `distinct` to remove duplicates if you have multiple data in the table for matching condition. You can remove it if not required in case it is not required.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you want to start with a query like this:

```
select s.house_id, u.email, hu.is_owner, u.is_active      
from subscriptions s left join
     house_user hu
     on s.house_id = hu.house_id left join
     users u
     on hu.user_id = u.id;
```

This does not return what you want, but it is rather unclear how your results are derived.

Comment: That's the problem I'm trying to figure out. Some users are in `house_contact` legacy table, some users are in `house_user` new table. They may be duplicated or just contained in one table. So I need to query results of both and unify the column `is_primary` with `is_owner`.