# Return NULL when no records found Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to solve Leetcode's second highest salary (https://leetcode.com/problems/second-highest-salary/). Here's what I implemented on postgres:

```
select foo.salary as "SecondHighestSalary"
from 
(select salary,
dense_rank() over (order by salary desc) as rank
from Employee) foo
where rank = 2;
```

But the issue is, I need to return NULL if there are no records with rank = 2.
I then tried

```
select (case
    when count(1) = 0 then NULL
    else salary
    end
)
from 
(select salary,
dense_rank() over (order by salary desc) as rank
from Employee) foo
where rank = 2
group by salary;
```

But it still returns no records.
How do I output NULL when no records are returned?

Comment: The linked [exercise from leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/second-highest-salary/) doesn't give a proper table definition. It matters whether `salary` can be NULL. Given that they *ask* for a NULL result, that's quite an omission.

Answer (score 5):

You don't actually need `COALESCE`, just an outer `SELECT`:

```sql
SELECT (
   SELECT salary FROM (
      SELECT salary, dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC NULLS LAST) AS rank
      FROM   employee
      ) sub
   WHERE  rank = 2
   LIMIT  1
   ) AS second_highest_salary;
```

See:

- [Return a value if no record is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098795/return-a-value-if-no-record-is-found/8098816#8098816)

Be sure to add `NULLS LAST` if `salary` can be `NULL`, or you are in for a surprise. (You'd get the *highest* salary.) See:

- [Sort NULL values to the end of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621205/sort-null-values-to-the-end-of-a-table/7622046#7622046)

And there can be multiple rows with `rank = 2`, so add `LIMIT 1`.

With an index on `salary`, [Schwern's 2nd query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70601577/939860) will be substantially faster, though - while dodging the `NULL` issue because `max()` excludes `NULL` values, and dodging the "no row" issue because aggregate functions always return a row, defaulting to `NULL` in absence of a value.

Answer (score 2):

The solution doesn't work because there's no row for the `case` to act on.

You can use `coalesce` and a sub-select.

Rewriting it as a CTE makes the sub-select more compact.

```
with ranked_salaries as (
  select
    salary,
    dense_rank() over (order by salary desc) as "rank"
  from Employee
)
select
  coalesce(
    (select salary from ranked_salaries where "rank" = 2),
    null
  );
```

---

Note that [this is a simpler and faster approach for this particular problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/second-highest-salary/solution/197728).

```
select max(salary)
from Employee
where salary < (select max(salary) from Employee)
```

If salary is indexed, this should be very fast.

Answer (score 2):

```
select max(salary) as "SecondHighestSalary"
from 
    (select salary,
        dense_rank() over (order by salary desc) as rnk
    from Employee) foo
where rnk = 2;
```

Using a dummy aggregate for the output will guarantee a row is returned. It also deals with the potential for tying rows.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT DISTINCT salary
   FROM Employee
   ORDER BY salary DESC
   LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) as SecondHighestSalary
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).